# Fix FluidRows between tabs

Tags: r, shiny

In shiny application , can we make the fluid rows fixed so that it appears in all subtabs. For example (refer below). In this example, the sliderInput comes only only in Subtab1, so Can we make this sliderInput fixed? so that it appears in Subtab2 as well?

```
tabPanel(
  "Tab",
  tabsetPanel(
    
      tabPanel(
        
      "Subtab1",
      fluidRow(
        sliderInput(............)
      ),
      fluidRow(
           ......
      )
            ),
      
      tabPanel("Subtab2",
             ...........
              )
      )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't.  That's because the content of each `tabPanel` is independent of the content of every other `tabPanel`.

If you mean "can I make it *look* like the `sliderInput` appears on every tab?", then the answer is "Yes".  Using a module would be the easiest way to do this. See [this page](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html) for more information about Shiny modules.

Alternatively, with a slight change of layout, you could have a single `sliderInput` above the `tabsetPanel`.

The better option would depend on what you want to do with the `sliderInput`s.  If the `sliderInput`(s) would each do the same thing, then the second option is probably best.  if the `sliderInput` on each tab is intended to do something different to all the other `sliderInput`s, then the modular approach is probably the way to go.